# how to use FBgraph package on Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement the package [enter link description here](https://github.com/stevezhu/meteor-fbgraph)
but can't follow the nodejs logic on this Package as there is no Meteor examples to follow , has anybody succeeded in using this Package on meteor ?